# Test that works on local machine not working on pipelines

Tags: typescript, npm, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, testcafe

So I wrote a test that I want to run and have tested it and it works perfectly on my local machine.  I then moved it to the pipeline in bitbucket and I get the following terminal output from my makefile

```
g++ -g -c run_test.cpp
g++ -g run_test.cpp -o rund
g++    -c -o run_magento_test.o run_magento_test.cpp
g++ -g run_magento_test.cpp -o runMd
./rund 1
../node_modules/.bin/testcafe -e chromium AutomatedTesting.js --screenshots ./screenshots --screenshots-on-fails
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
./runMd 1
../node_modules/.bin/testcafe -e chromium MagentoTesting.js --assertion-timeout 20000 --selector-timeout 50000 --screenshots ./screenshots --screenshots-on-fails
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I noted the /usr/bin/env and checked the output of the command

```
ls /usr/bin
```

and it definitely contains env then I checked the PATH variable which is

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

So now I am confused how it is not calling env correctly.

Also note that I know I am not supposed to push node_modules/ to bitbucket but  I did it and am going to fix this later does this have something to do with the problem?

In case anyone needs to know it is running 4.14.42-coreos

Comment: bitbucket pipelines run on docker images, and so will have different environment variables than your local machine.  Please retry your debugging in the image you are using, try running an executable shebanged as `#! /usr/bin/env node`, and if it's still a mystery, please post your bitbucket-pipelines.yml.

Comment: This error message means that the "node" Node.js binary is not found. Try to add the `which node` command to your pipeline and examine the output.